# Django model.save() not working with loaddata

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which is overriding save() to slugify a field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I run load data to load a fixture, this `save()` does not appear to be called because the slug field is empty in the database. Am I missing something?

I can get it to work by a pre_save hook signal, but this is a bit of a hack and it would be nice to get `save()` working.

```
def mymodel_pre_save(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    instance.slug = slugify(instance.name)

pre_save.connect(mymodel_pre_save, sender=MyModel)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No you're not. save() is NOT called by loaddata, by design (its way more resource intensive, I suppose).  Sorry.

EDIT: According to the docs, pre-save is not called either (even though apparently it is?).

Data is saved to the database as-is, according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#what-s-a-fixture

Comment: Hi @Dave, thanks for the info.

It seems to currently be working with pre-save though. The second piece of code above does result in the model instance having its slug field populated in the database.

Comment: Ya know that was my impression too... but then the docs said otherwise.  But I've been in the same place as you and never been able to get save() to work.

Comment: Hmm, the docs do say that pre_save is not called. But I just debugged the code and it does call pre_save. Trace from https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py#L180 to and https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py#L487 runs. Either the docs are wrong or bug?

Comment: You should definitely file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar now - I need a second model to have a parallel entry for each of the first model in the fixture.  The second model can be enabled/disabled, and has to retain that value across `loaddata` calls.  Unfortunately, having a field with a default value (and leaving that field out of the fixture) doesn't seem to work - it gets reset to the default value when the fixture is loaded (The two models could have been combined otherwise).

So I'm on Django 1.4, and this is what I've found so far:

- You're correct that `save()` is not called.  There's a special `DeserializedObject` that does the insertion, by calling `save_base()` on the Model *class* - overriding `save_base()` on your model won't do anything since it's bypassed anyway.
- @Dave is also correct:  the current docs *still* say the pre-save signal is not called, but it is.  It's behind a condition:  `if origin and not meta.auto_created`

  - `origin` is the class for the model being saved, so I don't see why it would ever be falsy.
  - `meta.auto_created` has been False so far with everything I've tried, so I'm not yet sure what it's for.  Looking at the Options object, it seems to have something to do with [abstract models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).
  - So yes, the `pre_save` signal is indeed being sent.
- Further down, there's a `post_save` signal behind the same condition that is also being sent.

Using the post_save signal works.  My models are more complex, including a ManyToMany on the "Enabled" model, but basically I'm using it like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Info(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()

class Enabled(models.Model):
   info = models.ForeignKey(Info)

def create_enabled(sender, instance, *args, **kwards):
   if Info == sender:
      Enabled.objects.get_or_create(id=instance.id, info=instance)

post_save.connect(create_enabled)
```

And of course, `initial_data.json` only defines instances of `Info`.